# Get top 5 most popular items in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that looks something like this:

```
user_id    photo_id
1          1
1          2
1          3
1          4
2          5
2          6
```

I want to get a list of the most popular users from it. Like this:

```
Popular Users: 1 (4) & 2 (2)
```

How would I go about doing that in mysql in PHP?

Thanks, Coulton

PS: I do know much about mysql commands so you don't have to dumb it down. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Same difference. That's what I meant.

Comment: How are you defining "popular"?

Comment: @Pete: I think he means the users that submitted the most photos.

Comment: @Mark Makes sense from his example.  It just wasn't explicit and you know what happens when we assume =P

Comment: Also it would be better to store the count of photos directly in users table as a precalculated value.

Comment: Been thinking about that, but users also delete photos. Would you suggest that? I don't really want to change the structure of my system for this one thing...

Comment: @phpnerd211: when user deletes photo - perform -1, when adds +1. My advice makes sence when you need to get the popular users often and have a lot of data, since the calculation + groupping + ordering over epxression can be slow.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The basic query would be:

```
select user_id, count(user_id) as cnt
from yourtable
group by user_id
order by cnt desc
```

To display the results, something like:

```
$results = array()
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {
   $results[] = "{$row['user_id']} ({$row['cnt']})"
   // repeat for however many results you want
}
echo "Popular user: ", implode(" &amp; ", $results);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select user_id, count(user_id) as count from table order by count desc group by user_id
```

something like that anyway...

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished using only SQL commands.  Here's what I'd do:

```
SELECT user_id, count(user_id) uid_count
FROM <<table>>
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY uid_count DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

GROUP BY collects rows that all have the same user_id, and ORDER BY ... DESC sorts the results in descending order, so the first rows represent the most popular users.  LIMIT gives you the top 5 results.

Answer (score 1):

The database query will look something like this:

```
select user_id, count(photo_id) as c 
from table group by user_id 
order by c desc limit 5;
```

In PHP, it would look something like this:

```
$sql = 'select user_id, count(photo_id) as c from table group by user_id order by c desc limit 5';
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['user_id'];
    echo $row['c'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(a.category_id) as cnt,b.category,b.image FROM bookings as a 
INNER JOIN service_category as b ON a.category_id=b.category_id 
GROUP BY a.category_id ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 6
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.